# How can i do for all triggers work correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a PHP code with 4 triggers where each one should open one video, but just the first trigger is opening. What's wrong? and how can I do for all works?

I've tried to change the var component but it didn't work at all

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  vid.play();
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  vid.pause();
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    vid.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">01_prescricao_enf_med</button>

<!-- Pop-up -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Conteúdo do Pop-up -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls>
        <source src="https://xxx.net.br/sin_saude/01_prescricao_enf_med.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">02_prescricao_enf_med</button>



<!-- Pop-up -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Conteúdo do Pop-up -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls>
        <source src="https://xxx.net.br/sin_saude/02_prescricao_enf_med.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">03_prescricao_orcamento</button>



<!-- Pop-up -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Conteúdo do Pop-up -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls>
        <source src="https://xxx.net.br/sin_saude/03_prescricao_orcamento.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">04_prescricao_orcamento</button>



<!-- Pop-up -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Conteúdo do Pop-up -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls>
        <source src="https://xxx.net.br/sin_saude/04_prescricao_orcamento.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to use unique IDs for each button, modal, and video.

Comment: ONE symptom of having duplicate id's (an HTML syntax error as they all MUST be unique) is that in some browsers only the first one loads with `var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");` but there is no defined fallback and you should fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to using IDs, basically either make them unique or don't use them at all. This is a great example of why I usually recommend not using IDs unless you really are careful.

For my answer I got rid of the IDs and replaced them with classes.

For the click handler, I delegate that to the body so I can use just one. Then I detect the class of the element clicked on. If it contains myBtn, then we know they are clicking to play a video.

Once the video button is detected, then I use `nextElementSibling` to get the next element after the button which is the modal. I add a class to that modal which displays the modal.

Then I look for the video in that modal and play it.

Then I have an else if statement looking to see if a click was on a modal or its children. If so, remove the active class and pause the video.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const el = ev.target;
  if (el.classList.contains("myBtn")) {
    const modal = el.nextElementSibling;
    modal.classList.add("active");        
    modal.querySelector("video").play();
  }
  else if(el.closest(".modal")) {
    const modal = el.closest(".modal");
    modal.classList.remove("active")
    modal.querySelector("video").pause();
  }
});
```

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;}

.modal {
  display: none;

}

.modal.active {
  display: block;
    position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:#fff
}
```

```html
<button class="myBtn">01_prescricao_enf_med</button>



<!-- Pop-up -->
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Conteúdo do Pop-up -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video width="100%" controls>
        <source src="https://xxx.net.br/sin_saude/01_prescricao_enf_med.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">02_prescricao_enf_med</button>



<!-- Pop-up -->
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Conteúdo do Pop-up -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video width="100%" controls>
        <source src="https://xxx.net.br/sin_saude/02_prescricao_enf_med.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">03_prescricao_orcamento</button>



<!-- Pop-up -->
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Conteúdo do Pop-up -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video width="100%" controls>
        <source src="https://xxx.net.br/sin_saude/03_prescricao_orcamento.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">04_prescricao_orcamento</button>



<!-- Pop-up -->
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Conteúdo do Pop-up -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <video width="100%" controls>
        <source src="https://xxx.net.br/sin_saude/04_prescricao_orcamento.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
  </div>

</div>
```